# TKinter: updating text value of the Label widget from a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I just took my first python Tutorial and am doing some tutorials.  This is my first exercise and I'm solving the problem differently as provided by the tutorial.  Tutorial has static display, meaning, it copies and pastes the same line over 10x to display the table.

However, I wanted it to be more dynamic based on a given range and using for loop to display it that many times.

I tried several ways of coding it, ie) coding the display in the same function where it was manipulated, etc ...

In the code I have also included "error checking" to find out the values at each stage.

However, as soon as the code goes to the "LABEL WIDGET" the value it renders is the last value of the loop, and not at each iteration.

Can someone help me with the code but most importantly explain to me WHY?  It looks like timing issues with updating the "thisLabel" variable, and maybe solved with delaying it?  I don't know how, but is there a better way of doing it?

```
from tkinter import *


def clearEntry():
    entryField.delete(0, END)


def showLabel(x):
    labelText.set(x)


# PROBLEM:  Label only renders the last item
def showTableText(x, y, z):
    base = str(x)
    factor = str(y)
    prod = str(z)
    print(base, factor, prod)
    tableText.set(base + "x" + factor + "=" + prod)
    print(tableText.get())
    thisLabel = Label(root, textvariable=tableText)
    thisLabel.pack()


def showTable():
    num = entryField.get()
    showLabel("Multiplication Table of " + num)
    x = int(num)
    for i in range(1, tableRange+1):
        prod = x*i
        print(x, "x", i, "=", prod)
        showTableText(x, i, prod)


root = Tk()

tableRange = 5

labelText = StringVar()
labelText.set("Multiplication Table")

tableText = StringVar()
tableText.set("---")

Label(root, textvariable=labelText).pack()

entryField = Entry(root, bg="yellow", fg="blue", text="Enter number")
entryField.pack()

Button(root, text="CLEAR", command=clearEntry).pack()
Button(root, text="SHOW TABLE", command=showTable).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9zu0.png)

Comment: ***"is there a better way of doing it?"***: Create the *Table* once and update the `Label(..., text=...`. This allows to reuse the *Table* like a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to understand what is StringVar() which is one of The Variable Classes of TKinter (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar). Variables can be used with most entry widgets to track changes to the entered value. They make the widgets connected to them change their value whenever the value of StringVar, IntVar .. etc changed. ([source](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm))

So in your case, you are making a StringVar in the global variable called `tableText` and you are passing it to all the Lable widgets you are creating. Inside the loop, you continually change the `tableText` value inside the function `showTableText` with the method `tableText.set(base + "x" + factor + "=" + prod)` so the next time in the loop when you change 'tableText' by the method 'set' it will change all the previously created Labels which are connected to `tableText` variable.

To solve the issue, move the global variable `tableText = StringVar()` to inside the function `showTableText`

So it will be like this:

```
def showTableText(x, y, z):
    base = str(x)
    factor = str(y)
    prod = str(z)
    print(base, factor, prod)
    tableText = StringVar() # Moved tableText to be a local variable inside this function
    tableText.set(base + "x" + factor + "=" + prod)
    print(tableText.get())
    thisLabel = Label(root, textvariable=tableText)
    thisLabel.pack()
```

So, are you wondering why it works now?
because now in each loop when the loop call `showTableText` function it will create a new instance of `StringVar()`. However, in your code, it is a global variable which means it is only creating once and you are reusing the same instance of StringVar for all Lables

Comment: this is great information and tyvm.  And thank u for providing the source to read up on!

Comment: If that solves your problem, then, please mark the answer as accepted so others can see it as solved and what solved it.

Comment: absolutely.  and a very elegant solution!